# Help with counter-example using conditional expectations

Tags: statistics, examples-counterexamples, conditional-expectation, independence

I am trying to construct a counter-example for a certain problem in a Statistics class. Right now, to finish the counter-example, I just need to find three random variables, let's say, $(X, Y, Z)$, such that:

1. $X$ and $Z$ are independent;
2. $E\left[Y | X\right] = 0$;
3. $E\left[Y | X, Z\right] \neq 0$;
4. $E\left[Y^2 | X, Z\right] = a \cdot Z + b \cdot X^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive scalars;
5. $E\left[Z\right] = 1$;

I couldn't prove that such a triplet does not exist either. Any simple ideas on how to come up with this triplet?

Comment: You could try to brute force it: Assume $X, Y, Z$ are discrete with pmfs f, g, h, and solve for f, g, h. I'm not sure how difficult this is.

Answer (score 0):

We could take any $Z$ of mean 1 (excluding constants) and any independent X. $Y$ could be defined conditionally as
$$Y \vert Z,X \sim \mathcal{D}\Big(f(Z), \quad aZ+bX^2-f(Z)^2\Big),$$
where $\mathcal{D}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a generic distribution of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $f$ is any function such that
$$ E\left(f(Z)\right)=0.$$
Now 1,2,3, and 5 come by construction, and using
$$ E\left(Y^2\right) =  \mathrm{Var}(Y) + E\left(Y\right)^2 $$
you should get 4.

We only need to prove that the variance can always be non-negative.

If we have no restrictions on the support of $X$ and $Z$, one could easily make sure that
$$bX^2 > f(Z)^2-aZ$$
for $f(Z) = Z-1$.